# issues with implementing bogosort

Tags: python, sorting, memory

For some reason I decided to implement the almighty bogosort in python, and I wrote the code below:

```
import numpy as np

def checkSorted(x):
  if x == sorted(x[:]):
    return True
  else:
    return False

def bogosort(x):
  np.random.shuffle(x)
  if checkSorted(x):
    return
  else:
    bogosort(x)

arr = [1,3,2]
bogosort(arr)
print(arr)
```

when the array size exceeded 4, I would get the following error:

> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Pythonobject

Yikes! I found the workaround which is:

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(50000)
```

this should be fine with an array size of 8, since 8! is 40320, but this time I ran into a segmentation fault!

> repl process died unexpectedly: signal: segmentation fault (core
>   dumped)

Yikes again! I think this time it's running out of memory and crashing. Is there a way to increase the allowed memory usage to prevent this?

I really want this algorithm to work with at least an array size of 10 so I can draw a graph comparing it to other algorithms, since something like quicksort can't even be timed with inputs of less than 10.

Comment: You don't need to use `x[:]`. `sorted()` doesn't modify the array, it returns a new array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since bogosort can take a very, very long time to run as the array size increases, you might be better off using **iteration** rather than **recursion**. This is because larger arrays will easily exceed the recursion depth.

Here, I have edited your code to use a loop. I also made some of your code more concise.

```
import random

def checkSorted(x):
    # A more concise way is to just return the comparison,
    # which will evaluate to either True or False.
    return x == sorted(x)

def bogosort(x):
    # Instead of using recursion, you could use iteration.
    # List x will continue to be shuffled until it is sorted.
    while not checkSorted(x):
        random.shuffle(x)
    # Once x is sorted, return it.
    return x

# Here, I just initialized arr as a list of integers from 0 to 5, excluding 5
arr = list(range(5))
# To test bogosort, let's shuffle the list beforehand
random.shuffle(arr)
# Run bogosort, then print the sorted array
bogosort(arr)
print(arr)
```

I also used Python's built-in `random` module. Though if you need to, you can freely use `numpy` instead.